# Does anyone know any RTL Compression tool?

Tags: winapi, compression

Does anyone know a good tool for compression files using Windows API function called RtlCompressBuffer? I want to compress an executable using this method.

Comment: Can you clarify what your asking/want to do?

Comment: This is programmers site, so what is reason not writing this tool by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RtlCompressBuffer is a fairly low-level tool. You'd normally use it to create some higher-level tool before actually compressing an executable.

Windows has a couple such higher level tools, depending on exactly what you want to accomplish. If you want an executable that's stored on a file system in compressed form, then you probably want to use NTFS compression. To compress your executable with this, you call `DeviceIoControl` with the [`FSCTL_SET_COMPRESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364592.aspx) flag.

If you want to compress a file for distribution (e.g., so a user will be able to download it faster) you normally want to put it into a cabinet file, which you might then ship by itself, or (generally preferred) package it up into an MSI package. As far as pre-packaged tools to do this, you'd be looking at Microsoft's [`cabarc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417343.aspx#top). If you want to do the job in your own code, you can use the [File Compression Interface (FCI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff797921).

Obligatory side note: although both of these do compression (and also support matching decompression), no I'm not really sure whether either (not to mention both) is actually implemented using RtlCompressBuffer. I don't believe Microsoft's documentation specifies their implementation in nearly that level of detail.